# Custom Object Detection Model with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I'm training a custom model for my project. I'm working with [this Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi/blob/master/Train_TFLite2_Object_Detction_Model.ipynb#scrollTo=eGEUZYAMEZ6f). But I have some errors when i tried to create record files. I tried delete this files, but when i deleted it the error continue with other files. I thinked the error is related with max file count or so long file name, but I can't solve it.

My Colab Code:

```
!python3 create_csv.py
!python3 create_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images/train_labels.csv --labelmap=labelmap.txt --image_dir=images/train --output_path=train.tfrecord
!python3 create_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images/validation_labels.csv --labelmap=labelmap.txt --image_dir=images/validation --output_path=val.tfrecord
```

create_tfrecord.py

```
# Script to create TFRecord files from train and test dataset folders
# Originally from GitHub user datitran: https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset/blob/master/generate_tfrecord.py

"""
Usage:
  # From tensorflow/models/
  # Create train data:
  python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images/train_labels.csv --image_dir=images/train --output_path=train.record

  # Create test data:
  python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images/test_labels.csv  --image_dir=images/test --output_path=test.record
"""
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import io
import pandas as pd

from tensorflow.python.framework.versions import VERSION
if VERSION >= "2.0.0a0":
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
else:
    import tensorflow as tf

from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('labelmap', '', 'Path to the labelmap file')
flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir', '', 'Path to the image directory')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    labels = []
    with open(FLAGS.labelmap, 'r') as f:
        labels = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(int(labels.index(row['class'])+1))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):
    # Load and prepare data
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.image_dir)
    examples = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input)

    # Create TFRecord files
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.output_path)
    print('Successfully created the TFRecords: {}'.format(output_path))

    # Create labelmap.pbtxt file
    path_to_labeltxt = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.labelmap)
    with open(path_to_labeltxt, 'r') as f:
        labels = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    
    path_to_labelpbtxt = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'labelmap.pbtxt')
    with open(path_to_labelpbtxt,'w') as f:
        for i, label in enumerate(labels):
            f.write('item {\n' +
                    '  id: %d\n' % (i + 1) +
                    '  name: \'%s\'\n' % label +
                    '}\n' +
                    '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

Error :

```
Successfully converted xml to csv.
Successfully converted xml to csv.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/create_tfrecord.py", line 120, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 36, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/content/create_tfrecord.py", line 98, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "/content/create_tfrecord.py", line 46, in create_tf_example
    encoded_jpg = fid.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 114, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 76, in _preread_check
    self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /content/images/train/cone_de_signalisation_jpg.rf.64d539df00fc20d8889f93ec8b9c3763.jpg; No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/create_tfrecord.py", line 120, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 36, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/content/create_tfrecord.py", line 98, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "/content/create_tfrecord.py", line 46, in create_tf_example
    encoded_jpg = fid.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 114, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 76, in _preread_check
    self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /content/images/validation/cone_de_signalisation_jpg.rf.7ccceaae115376af761d854d34e24397.jpg; No such file or directory
```